# Как сменить версию в VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Собственно, где можно сменить версию проекта в Visual Studio 2017? Куда тыкать?
Меня интересует конкретно смена версии моего выходно приложения

Comment: О какой версии вы говорите? Уточните в вашем вопросе. То что вы написали не понятно, версия "Чего" у решений нет никаких версий, есть версии пакетов, стандартов, версии собираемого приложения которое пишется в описании файла.

Comment: меня интересует смена версии приложения